# h:commandButton's action not being invoked

Tags: jsf, richfaces

i'm using JSF 2.0 and I'm having a commandButton inside div section in home.xhml. it's not working. I don't see the destinationPage, remaining only in home.xhtml.

home.xhmtl:

```
<div id="left_side">
    <ui:include src="login.xhtml" />
        <h:form>
           <h:commandButton value="register" action="register"/>
        </h:form>
</div>
```

register.xhtml is inside a h:body and a h:form

and the faces-config.xml configuration:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>home.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>register.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If  `home.xhtml` and `register.xhtml` are at the root of your application, then you need to define the navigation rule as follows:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/home.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/register.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Otherwise you add the path relative to the root.. which would be indicated by a backlash

**Update**

Actually in your case it seems that you do not really need the POST request which is generated by the`commandButton`. A simple button which would generate a GET request seems to be sufficient:

```
<h:button outcome="register" value="register" />
```

Comment: whey are in webapp(root)/templates.. so, i've added:  <from-view-id>/templates/home.xhtml</from-view-id> and <to-view-id>/templates/register.xhtml</to-view-id>.. things didn't get better..

Comment: try out my updated answer

Comment: done.. now it writes on the register button: disabled because a navigation case could not be matched...the faces-config configuration is problematic ? why so ?

Comment: where did you place it? also please add the content along with web.xml

Comment: i've added in WEB-INF(the faces config file).. there is also web.xml(who contents: <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    ..
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ..
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-par

Comment: sorry.. faild to edit answer that's why i've commented with the web.xml content

Comment: @BalusC.. i've updated web.xml conforming to the duplicated question but no impruvement..also, i don't have nested forms.. my div section is inside f:view.. it says: Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/list.xhtml' for action 'register' with outcome 'register'... in list.xhml is my welcome file with has the template home and home has the commandButton with register.xhmtl...